# Sharepoint 2010 FBA Site and Opera

Tags: sharepoint-2010, opera, fba

I have a SP2010 site with FBA enabled. I can open it using Firefox and Internet Explorer with no problem. But it gives me a 403 FORBIDDEN error when I try to open with Opera 11.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find this error due to Microsoft Office Live Add-in 1.3. Uninstall it if you have installed it. Have a look at [this](http://vettekerry.wordpress.com/2009/05/21/403-forbidden-and-forms-authentication-with-moss/)

Comment: I think it's not the case for me, because I don't have it installed on this machine.

Comment: Go through this : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2010/01/07/bug-http-403-forbidden-with-fba-sharepoint-site.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the MS Office Live Add-in problem you're hitting with Opera.

Opera 12.16's user-agent string on Win7/64 bit is:

Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Edition United States Local) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16

And since that doesn't have "Mozilla" anywhere in it, Sharepoint assumes it's a WebDav client.

Here's what's really going on:
http://blog.imason.com/sharepoint-fba-and-the-403-forbidden-error/

```
From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc250199(PROT.10).aspx

<4>
 Section 2.2.8: The WebDAV server in Windows Windows SharePoint Services 3.0
 technology checks the product tokens in the User-Agent request-header field sent
 with a request for the presence of “Mozilla” and the absence of either “Office”,
 “FrontPage”, or “non-browser” to determine whether to send an HTTP 302 redirect
 message to a login page when using ASP.NET Forms Authentication for
 unauthenticated clients. Otherwise, the server assumes that the client user
 agent is not a browser and will return either an HTTP 401 “Unauthorized” error
```